# Dragon Dictate often turns the microphone on after mistakenly believing I have said "wake up"

Tags: voice-dictation

In [Dragon Dictate 4](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm), the voice command *"wake up"* can be used to turn the voice recognition on (provided that the microphone was asleep, not off). It tends to get triggered too easily: when I discuss around with colleagues as the microphone is asleep, Dragon often believes I have said "wake up", and subsequently turn the microphone on. Is there any way to avoid this situation?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.